# Grunt is not working on windows

Tags: gruntjs

here is my code, the error is: 
Warning: task "concat" not found

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';',
    },
    dist: {
      src: ['calculation/index.js', 'calculation/test.js'],
      dest: 'dist/built.js',
    },
  },
});
    grunt.loadNpmTask("grunt-contrib-contat");
    grunt.registerTask('default',['concat'])
;};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply need to move the registration of your `grunt-contrib-concat` task above the point where the config is looking for it.

Comment: Move the line starting with `grunt.loadNpmTask...` before the line starting with `grunt.initConfig...`

Comment: no, it didn't work... but it should work with the function at the end... because of hoisting